# Casting an NSTimeInterval as a NSNumber within a block

Tags: ios, casting, nsnumber, nstimeinterval

I'm having difficulty within a block with assigning an NSTimeInterval value to an NSNumber

Here is what I have so far:

```
[player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(3, 10) queue:NULL usingBlock:^(CMTime time){
            NSTimeInterval seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
            NSNumber *lastTime = 0;
            for (NSDictionary *item in bualadhBos) {
                NSNumber *time = item[@"time"];
                if ( seconds > [time doubleValue] && seconds > [lastTime doubleValue]) {

                    lastTime = [seconds doubleValue];// this line causes difficulties
                    NSString *str = item[@"line"];
                    break;
                }; }

          }
```

I'm keeping track of time in an NSNumber and when the if statement is true I need to assign a new value to the variable lastTime - the problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to assign a NSTimeInterval Value contained in seconds to the variable lastTime that is of type NSNumber.  I'm really confused as everything I read tells me that both are really just doubles.   Any ideas?

Comment: NSTimeInterval is just an alias for the scalar/primitive `double` type, whereas NSNumber is a class.  You cannot "cast" between a scalar and an object in Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand that `seconds` is a primitive type (`NSTimeInterval` - really `double`). `lastTime` is the class type `NSNumber`.

To create an `NSNumber` from a primitive number type, you can do:

```
lastTime = @(seconds);
```

This is modern syntax for `lastTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:seconds]`.

And the line `NSNumber *lastTime = 0;` is technically correct but not really and it's misleading. You want:

```
NSNumber *lastTime = nil;
```

Don't confuse primitive numbers with `NSNumber` and objects.

BTW - none of this is related to the use of a block.